# CalculateField_management - Updating a field with value from another field?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have automatically generated X/Y coordinates using arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management but want to rename these fields. I've planned to do this by adding a new field for MidX and MidY then using CalculateField_management to update this new field with the value from the old one ("MID_X" and "MID_Y")

This isn't working:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/213664/edit) your question to include the error that you are getting.

Comment: Please always include errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [24046: Tool  cannot use VB expressions for services](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/sharing-workflows/24046-tool-cannot-use-vb-expressions-for-services.htm), the problem could be related to using VB expressions in 64-bit ArcGIS products. As offered in the very same page, if you change your parser to Python, your problem should disappear.